# SMTP error on Ganib on 64bit Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

ive looked through quite afew documents on this ganib program but they're really hard to find and im still unable to make it work... so heres my problem... im running an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit. Ive installed all the files required to make java work on a 64bit system and ganib runs. It runs into problems at 2 areas... first when clicking on forgotten password and second when trying to assign a task.

I found a SQL 'patch' on the developers site for problem 2 which made the eror message go away but it dident fix the problem.

Here is a log of catalina.out for the forgot password area (i cleared the catalina.out started ganib and then clicked on forgot password):

```
2014-01-14 13:51:03,836 INFO  com.ganib.scheduler.SchedulerSetupServlet - Startup:  deleting old quartz jobs.
2014-01-14 13:51:03,895 INFO  com.ganib.scheduler.SchedulerSetupServlet - Startup:  submitting new quartz jobs.
2014-01-14 13:51:03,919 INFO  org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext - Refreshing org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@101a031: display name [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@101a031]; startup date [Tue Jan 14 13:51:03 SGT 2014]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@11a01dd
2014-01-14 13:51:03,971 INFO  org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext - Bean factory for application context [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@101a031]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@df42ce
Using stylesheet compilation
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: successfully loaded file: /mnt/data2/Ganib-1.3_with_jre/jre-lin/lib/javamail.address.map
Exception while sending mail: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.Session cannot be cast to javax.mail.Session
2014-01-14 13:51:30,338 INFO  org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext - Closing org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@101a031: display name [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@101a031]; startup date [Tue Jan 14 13:51:03 SGT 2014]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@11a01dd
2014-01-14 13:51:30,557 INFO  org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing
```

Comment: tomcat ?? Or any other app ??

Answer (score 0):

This must be due to mail.jar file in your in WEB-INF/lib  (if I am not wrong its tomcat catalina dump)

This is probably a class loading issues.

delete mail.jar from there and check

Actually mail.jar must be in tomcat lib as well as in WEB-INF/lib of application path.

so there is two copies of mail.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Delete mail.jar from **\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib**
and try again.. this will resolve your problem

Thanks,